# Python regular expression to remove all text between <> symbols

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a set of sentences of the form

```
"<S>Today is a <unk> sunny day and <num> children are playing outside </S>"
```

I would like to remove all text between <> symbols, so that the output sentence is

```
"Today is a sunny day and children are playing outside"
```

How can I do this using a regular expression in Python?

Comment: `str = re.sub(r'\s*<[^>]*>\s*', ' ', str)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer here.

You can use:

```
import re

str = re.sub(r'\s*<[^>]*>\s*', ' ', str)
```

Regex `\s*<[^>]*>\s*` matches a string that starts with `<` and ends with `>` surrounded by optional whitespaces on either side.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could simply search for the <> symbols and replace the String with nothing ("") so that these symbols will be deleted from the string.

EDIT: Here is my new regex Example:

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/CNptDR/3)

Comment: I don't think python supports `U` https://regex101.com/r/CNptDR/2

Comment: @mrzasa yes you're totally right I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<[^>]*>
```

You just lock on the must-remove target, and match the target, and remove that.

In python,

```
ss="""<S>Today is a <unk> sunny day and <num> children are playing outside </S>"""
regx= re.compile(r'<[^>]*>')
print(regx.sub("",ss))
```

Output is

```
Today is a  sunny day and  children are playing outside
```

Comment: This doesn't get rid of the extra whitespace though.

Comment: I think this case is for removing `<..>` block  . Thank you:-)